# c++ using 16bit pointers on 32/64 bit systems

Tags: c++, pointers, 16-bit

Typically the size of a pointer is equal the "width" of the CPU, so that a pointer can typically access every system address.

Using a 16 bit pointer on a 64 bit system should allow to fit 4 16bit pointers in the same memory area as a single 64bit pointer, however a 16bit pointer only allows to address 2^16 locations.

My idea is not about saving memory, but about potential performance benefits. The idea is basically to allocate memory in chunks of 65635 and use 16 bit pointers to address those "virtual" 16bit address spaces.

Is this possible? Should I try to do it i.e. will it offer a performance benefit?

Comment: The only way to know is try and profile. But I doubt it.

Comment: Performance benefit? You can do it and test, but I don't see any theoretical reason for why it should be faster. I am afraid you could start moving data from 32 to 64 bit registers on amd64 for no good reason, when converting from your magic 16-bit pointers to true 64 bits addresses used by the CPU...

Comment: Why do you think this would improve performance? What do you think would be faster this way and why?

Comment: One would still need to add the address of the beginning of the 64KB block to the 16-bit offset in it before reading/writing memory. So, one loss is right there, in extra instructions being executed, in overall bigger code (with effects on the cache) and possibly less efficient use of registers.

Comment: Well, that analogy might not apply to computing but I will have an easier time operating a 16 inch saw on an appropriate size workbench. The same way I will have an easier time carrying 16 pounds rather than 32 pounds, and in both cases I will probably get the job done faster. I am aware there will be a performance hit due to the implementation, but I assume 16 bit pointers will align nicely to a 32 or 64bit processor, so the question is will the savings from using 16 bit pointers, IF ANY, outweigh the performance penalty. I know nvidia implemented virtual system addressing for cuda use...

Answer (score 5):

More likely it will be a peformance hit. Modern CPU can access 32 and 64 bit data width easily. If you have 16 bit data you need need masking and so on to calculate the real address in the CPU.

A pointer for further reading is unaligned access.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, if you have a 32/64-bit system, it has enough RAM that the optimization benefits of your scheme would be outweighed by the complication of implementing it. You'd need to make sure it worked correctly, and your scheme would operate much slower than a direct pointer access.